# Scala 2D Animation library

Tags: scala, animation, java-2d

Can anyone recommend a good 2D animation package for Scala? I prefer something which already have some basic events handling, more like `JavaFX` than like `processing.org`.

Comment: Since Scala runs on the JVM and interoperates with Java very well, you could just use a Java library and use that from Scala.

Comment: Pure Java libraries don't take advantage of all scala's goodies. But I'll be glad for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at [Wiggle](http://code.google.com/p/wiggle/)?

Comment: Demo code looks nice, but (1) there's no documentation and (2) it's rendered with openGL only. (3) It's library looks pretty thin too (the only shape is rectangle in trunk). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used piccolo2d with Scala, and it worked out nicely.  Here's another [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/piccolo2d-users/browse_thread/thread/e9164455029c5302) along those lines, or visit www.piccolo2d.org for a more general introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for something like processing, you can use processing directly. It's called SPDE and [you can get it here](http://technically.us/spde/About). It's really nice.

Here are a couple of applets written in Scala using SPDE ([Rosetta Clock](http://blog.garritys.org/2009/12/rosetta-clock.html), [Starlings](http://blog.garritys.org/2009/11/spde-starlings.html)).

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote processing.org has no event handling, and thus I prefer something which is more abstract. (quoting myself "more like JavaFX than like processing.org")

Comment: I misread you. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice scala api wrapper for JavaFX: http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/